Rapidfuzz normalized similarity issue with Jaro/JaroWinkler distances
When performing fuzzy string matching via the rapidfuzz python library (version 3.5.2) for a large set of strings, I had noticed that for the JaroWinkler (JW) and Jaro normalized similarities, the similarity matrices may contain wrong values.
Concretely, in the below screenshot, the normalized JW similarity changes from 0.984737 to 0.9005848 when including a single string more. This also happens for normalized Jaro similarities. The issue seems to not be present for the default scorer (based on distances.Indel.normalized_similarity). Attempts to reproduce the issue in various other ways were not very successful.

After upgrading to the latest version 3.9.6 of rapidfuzz, the issue appears to be fixed:

Could you tell me what may have caused the issue and what scope the bug had (i.e. under which circumstances did it occur concretely)?
